# Dates in array lose formatting after 1st iteration of looping over the array

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm pulling CSV data from a URL.
I've parsed this into a variable called 'data'. It looks like this:

```
[
[ID, Sometext (dd-MM-YYYY), Othertext (dd-MM-YYYY), Whatevertext (dd-MM-YYYY)],
[1, yes, no, no],
[2, yes, yes, no],  
[3, no, yes, no],
etc...
]
```

If a certain text is present in the 1st array (the csv headers), it should be assigned another text.
The dates aren't ordered chronologically, but they should be.

I've made a loop to go over the headers, extracted the date, changed it to Date type, and replaced the text as required. Put both values into an array and used a sort function to order the arrays by date.

```
[
[Thu Aug 27 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2020, Text1], [Fri Aug 28 09:00:00 GMT+02:00 2020, Text2], [Sat Aug 29 09:00:00 GMT+02:00 2020, Text3]
etc.
]
```

Next I am looping over the following rows, if a value equals yes, I'm adding the new header value to an array for that ID. At the end of the iteration, I want to convert back the Date types to dd-MM-YYYY format.

In the first iteration, this works fine. But in the 2nd iteration, it gives an error since the dates are not Date types anymore.

Now I know this is pretty ugly with multiple nested loops, but for as far as I can tell, the changing of the values in data[0] is done before the next set of loops starts. And the new values are present in the 1st iteration but not in the 2nd. I don't understand why?

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);

var data = Utilities.parseCsv(response, ";")

for (var i = 7; i < data[0].length; i++) {
  
    var type;
    
if (/text1/.test(data[0][i]) === true) {
        type = "Text 1";
    } else if 
      (/text2/.test(data[0][i]) === true) { 
      type = "Text 2";
      } else if 
        (/text3/.test(data[0][i]) === true) {
      type = "Text 3";
        } else if 
          (/text4/.test(data[0][i]) === true) {
      type = "Text 4";
          } else if 
      (/text5/.test(data[0][i]) === true) { 
      type = "Text5";
      };
                
    data[0][i] = data[0][i].match(/\(([^)]+)\)/)[1]
    
    var dateParts = data[0][i].split("-");
data[0][i] = [new Date(+ dateParts[2], dateParts[1] - 1, + dateParts[0], 9, 0 ,0)];

    data[0][i].push(type)
    }; 
  
   
  var idsArray = [];
  
  for (var j = 1; j < data.length; j++) {

   var id = [];

    for (var k = 7; k < data[j].length; k++) {
      if (data[j][k] === "yes") {
        id.push(data[0][k])
      };
           
      };
        

    id.sort(sortFunction);   
  
  
    
for (var m = 0; m < id.length; m++) {
 id[m][0] = Utilities.formatDate(id[m][0], "Europe/Amsterdam", "dd-MM-yyyy");
  }

     id.unshift(data[j][3]);
      idsArray.push(id);
   
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use [`Utilities.formatDate()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate,-timezone,-format) in the statement

```js
id[m][0] = Utilities.formatDate(id[m][0], "Europe/Amsterdam", "dd-MM-yyyy");
```

you are changing the data type of the data stored in `id[m][0]` from `Date` to `string`.

What is the data stored in `id[m][0]`?  You put `data[0][k]` in there:

```
id.push(data[0][k])
```

Now the question is, did it *copy* the `Date` from `data` and give you a new `Date` for the `id` array?  No, JavaScript doesn't copy objects; you just have a reference to the original `Date` object, stored in the `data` array.

So you have indirectly mutated the values in `data` by updating some other array (`id`) that you thought was independent.

Update your mutating statement so you don't overwrite the existing object.

```js
var dateString = Utilities.formatDate(id[m][0], "Europe/Amsterdam", "dd-MM-yyyy");
```

Comment: "you have indirectly mutated the values in data by updating some other array (id) that you thought was independent." <= that solved it for me, thanks!